# Date/Time Graph With Counts in R

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to create a graph with my data. My information consists on a CSV that contains multiple lines with the following format: **date;time;hasconnection**.

**date** - Date of the occurrence.

**time** - Time of the occurrence (Morning, Afternoon, Night).

**hasconnection** - Has internet connection? (0 - False, 1 - True).

My idea is to create a graph that contains all this information. For example the Y axis will contains the time category (Morning,Afternoon,Night) and the X axis will contain the date. The graph will represent the number (count) of Success Internet Connection (1) and No Internet Connection (0).

Example of data in CSV:

```
22/04/2016;Morning;1  
22/04/2016;Night;0  
23/04/2016;Morning;1  
23/04/2016;Afternoon;1  
24/04/2016;Afternoon;0  
25/04/2016;Night;1  
25/04/2016;Night;0  
25/04/2016;Morning;1
```

Desired Graph Example:

[image: Desired Graph]

With **ggplot** I'm able to create the Y Axis (Morning, Afternoon,...) and the X Axis (dates..). I just don't know on how can I put the connection count data in the graph.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `geom_label()` utilizing the `hjust` aesthetic as well as the `fill` aesthetic. I generated some sample data to demonstrate:

```
set.seed(123) 
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(X = sample(letters[1:3], 100, replace = T), #like date
                 Y = sample(c('morn','day','night'), 100, replace = T),
                 Z = rbinom(100,1,prob = .6))
df2 <- df %>% group_by(X, Y, Z) %>% summarise(Counts = n())

ggplot(df2, aes(x = X, y= Y))+
  geom_label(aes(label = Counts, fill = factor(Z), hjust = Z)) + theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('0' = 'red','1' = 'green'), name = 'Indicator')
```

[image]

And then just play around with whatever plot options you want.

Comment: just one question. Ive made this and it is working but the color box values are too far apart. In your example they stick together.

Comment: @RicardoRacciore, is your `hasconnection` variable coded as a `factor` within your `data.frame`? also, it might be hard to answer any specific questions without knowing what your data looks like.

Comment: Once again... THANK YOU! I had them as a regular string. Just changed them to factor.

Comment: @RicardoRacciore The `hjust` might work better if they're just coded as numeric: 1 or 0...

Comment: worked like a charm! Thanks! Im also trying to order the X axis that contains Dates in asceding order. Ive tried to order the df but so far no luck.

Comment: it depends on how `R` read your date into the `data.frame`. check out the `as.Date` function